# Android Http Basic Authenticate Request from Ruby on Rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, http, authentication

I have a Ruby On Rails app online which uses devise authentication.
I am trying to make an android app which make a request from ror app when a user try to log in (so the users can use same account from ror app).
I heard that what I need is basic http authentication. Can you help me please with a functional example, or some useful links? All the examples found on the internet were useless.

Thanks

Comment: http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/

Comment: it works. thanks! you can add this comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: well, this link worked for you. I have added below as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit this url. It is very useful for [Ruby on Rails and Android Authentication](http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/).